# Problems running carla on UbuntuStudio 21.04

Tags: ubuntu-studio

I don't know why carla is not working anymore on my system.

This is the error msg:

```
Carla 2.3.2 started, status:
  Python version: 3.9.5
  Qt version:     5.15.2
  PyQt version:   5.15.4
  Binary dir:     /usr/lib/carla
  Resources dir:  /usr/share/carla/resources
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/carla/carla", line 46, in <module>
    host = initHost(initName, libPrefix, False, False, True)
  File "/usr/share/carla/carla_host.py", line 3227, in initHost
    gCarla.utils = CarlaUtils(utilsname)
  File "/usr/share/carla/carla_utils.py", line 333, in __init__
    self.lib.carla_cocoa_set_transient_window_for.argtypes = [c_uintptr, c_uintptr]
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 387, in __getattr__
    func = self.__getitem__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 392, in __getitem__
    func = self._FuncPtr((name_or_ordinal, self))
AttributeError: /usr/lib/carla/libcarla_utils.so: undefined symbol: carla_cocoa_set_transient_window_for
```

I already tried upgrading (Everything is up to date), searching for bugs in the carla GitHub (found nothing relevant) and reinstalling carla.

Comment: Compiling the latest Carla from [git](https://github.com/falkTX/Carla) works.

Comment: Really it depends on installation method. Both Carla from [official ubuntu repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/hirsute/carla) and from [ubuntustudio backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/~ubuntustudio-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+packages?field.name_filter=carla&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=hirsute) works normally on fresh 21.04 system. What did you have for `dpkg -l | grep carla` and `dpkg -S /usr/lib/carla/libcarla_utils.so` before compilation?

Comment: Both commands returned the 2.3.0-0ubuntu1 package. But just to be sure I purged all Carla packages and reinstalled. Now everything works! 
The libcarla_utils.so is the same, but /usr/share/carla/carla_utils.py changed and don't call carla_cocoa_set_transient_window_for anymore

Comment: To indicate that problem is solved I have added answer below.

Comment: Thanks, I added what I did to maybe help others with similar problems.

Answer (score 1):

My system was in a borked state for some reason.
I was able to get fix the problem by running:

```
sudo apt purge carla
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install carla
```

My guess is I updated /usr/share/carla/* a long time ago and forgot about it. When the system updated, some files got overwritten, but others not.

Answer (score 0):

The Carla version in your question indicates that its origin is [ubuntustudio backports PPA](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntustudio-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports/+packages?field.name_filter=carla&field.status_filter=published&field.series_filter=hirsute).

I would recommend to add this PPA and reinstall carla packages by

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntustudio-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install --reinstall $(dpkg -l | grep carla | grep ^ii | awk '{print $2}')
```